# how much time is accurated when schedule_timeout() is used?

Tags: linux-kernel

I have a question when schedule_timeout()
if A task wants to sleep for 500 msec, A will use the schedule_timeout() function.
but after 500msec, scheduler will get event and check the ready tasks in queue and run the highest priority task B. but it is not A task. that is, A task will run when A has highest priority in run queue. if it is true, we can't guarantee wakeup time. right?

Answer (score 0):

`schedule_timeout()` guarantees that **at least** specified period of time was passed.

So, in that case task `A` will run in **at least** 500 msec.